# About SeDebugPrivilege Token

Tags: delphi

i have a question.

How can i create a SeDebugPrivilege token in a process who already have it removed by another program?

```
var
  NewState      : TTokenPrivileges;
  luid          : TLargeInteger;
  hToken        : THandle;
  ReturnLength  : DWord;
begin
  OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, hToken);

  LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, 'SeDebugPrivilege', luid);

  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Luid [%d]', [luid]));

  NewState.PrivilegeCount           := 1;
  NewState.Privileges[0].Luid       := luid;
  NewState.Privileges[0].Attributes := SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

  AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, False, NewState, SizeOf(NewState), nil, ReturnLength);
  CloseHandle(hToken);
```

This code can enable/disable the token (if already exists), but if the token was removed he don't add it again. And is what i need.

I asked it because i don't know if you know the program called Deep Freezer, he remove SeDebugPrivilege privilege from all running processes.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to do this with an injection hooking dll that in turn calls AdjustTokenPrivileges()

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secbp/changing-privileges-in-a-token) says this is not possible:  *"After a privilege is removed from a token, it cannot be put back."*

Comment: If you removed you can't set it using AdjustTokenPrivileges(), only if he already exist.